# Query to split String value into multiple rows

Tags: sql, split

i have

```
id | dvr
1  | 1,2,3
2  | 1,3,4
3  | 1,5,6,7,8
```

and would like to have

```
id | dvr
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
2  | 1
2  | 3
2  | 4
... and so on
```

what is the fastest query i should use?

Comment: What's your DBMS? Anyway there are tons of answers about this.

Comment: It very much depends on what database you are using. Please update your question with this vital information.

Comment: Another thing, which we greatly value before answering any questions is to show us what was your attempt at writing a query and find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Make a sql function as below:

```
create Function [dbo].[fun_CSVToTable] 
(
    @LIST varchar(7000),
    @Delimeter varchar(10)
)
RETURNS @RET1 TABLE (RESULT BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RET TABLE(RESULT BIGINT)

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@LIST))='' RETURN  

    DECLARE @START BIGINT
    DECLARE @LASTSTART BIGINT
    SET @LASTSTART=0
    SET @START=CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@LIST,0)

    IF @START=0
    INSERT INTO @RET VALUES(SUBSTRING(@LIST,0,LEN(@LIST)+1))

    WHILE(@START >0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RET VALUES(SUBSTRING(@LIST,@LASTSTART,@START-@LASTSTART))
        SET @LASTSTART=@START+1
        SET @START=CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@LIST,@START+1)
        IF(@START=0)
        INSERT INTO @RET VALUES(SUBSTRING(@LIST,@LASTSTART,LEN(@LIST)+1))
    END

    INSERT INTO @RET1 SELECT * FROM @RET
    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running postgresql and dvr column is text you could do:

```
select
  id,
  unnest(string_to_array(dvr,','))
from your_table;
```

Comment: i'm using MS sql server